# Text + Images in CDATA Block

Tags: objective-c, image, parsing, text, cdata

So I ineed to parse data from a CDATA block.

It can look like

```
<![CDATA[Important text I need<span style=" color:#000000;"><img src="imageName.jpg" alt="imageName" border=0 style="vertical-align:text-bottom;" /></span>Still important text]]>
```

or

```
<![CDATA[Important text I need]]>
```

or

```
<![CDATA[imageName.jpg]]>
```

or something like this.

The result should be an array, in cas of the first example the content of the array would be
"Important text I need",
"imageName.jpg",
"Still important text"

The result of the other would be an array with one object containing either the imageName or the text.

I am stuck with this issue for a while now since I am not really good at regular expressions.
Has anybody here ever had the same problem and how did you solve it?

Or is there an easy workaround I have missed yet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you only have html inside cdata you could go for NSXMLParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came to my own solution:
The first method searches the cdataString for any HTML.
If the cdataString contains any HTML, I search for the occurancy of "src=...".

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)htmlString {
    NSRange r;
    while ((r = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound){
        // substring from htmlString starting with "<" and ends with ">"
        NSString *substring     = [htmlString substringWithRange:r];

        //new Image String, stays empty if no image is found
        NSString *imageString   = @"";

        //length >= 9 because shortest possible result can be length nine, i.e. "src=1.png"
        if (substring.length >= 9) {

            //substring contains String "src=" ?
            NSRange imageRange      = [substring rangeOfString:@"src=[^>]+" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
            if (imageRange.location != NSNotFound) {

                //find the image name
                imageString  = [self imageFromHTMLString:substring];
            }
            //set the image string the imagename + my seperator tag
            imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"##__##%@##__##",imageString];
        }
        //replace html stuff with either emty string or my imagename
        htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:imageString];

    }
    return htmlString;
}
- (NSString *)imageFromHTMLString:(NSString *)htmlString{
    NSRange range;

    NSString *result = @"";
    while ((range = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"src=[^>]+ " options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound) {

        htmlString  = [[[htmlString substringWithRange:range] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        result      = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"src=" withString:@""];
    }

    return result;

}
```

The Methods are used with:

```
myCdataString = [self stringByStrippingHTML:myCdataString];
```

The Return Value is a String with the format:

```
Important Text I need##__##ImageName.png##__##More ImportantText I need
```

Creating an Array can be done via componentsSeparatedByString:@"##__##"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `NSXMLParser` there's a delegate method called `foundCDATA` which looks like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock{
    if (!parseElement) {
        return;
    }
    if (parsedElementData==nil) {
        parsedElementData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    [parsedElementData appendData:CDATABlock];

    //Grabs the whole content in CDATABlock.
    NSMutableString *content = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 }
```

Now add [this prewritten class](https://gist.github.com/leighmcculloch/1202238) to your project. Then import it to the parser class you want to use it in:

`#import NSString_stripHTML`

Now simply you can add the following line to `foundCDATA`method:

```
NSString *strippedContent;
strippedContent = [content strippedHtml];
```

Now you will have the stripped text without any extra characters. You can substring whatever you want from this stripped text.